# How to make a contact card for a child in case they get lost?

Tags: primary-schooler, safety, travel, outdoor

We are going a field trip and we are taking our 5-year-old child with us. I want to make a contact card for him, which sticks on his back, in case (God forbid) he gets lost so anyone can contact us. Now the problem is that I couldn't find any template or idea to create one.

Can some one suggest any idea or direct me a link so I can make/get some cards or idea for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The card:**

I would make a few business-card-sized cards. Put one in a jacket pocket, one in a pants pocket, and one in his backpack. Hide one in his shoe if you're really worried.

For more visibility, you could also give your son a [lanyard with an ID card pocket](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_g38QY66TQ58/S_QOYBvg0PI/AAAAAAAAAHA/d0eKS1u53Yo/s1600/lanyard_clip_on_lanyard.jpg) and stick a card in that.

I would laminate the cards to make them durable against water and folding/tearing.

**The text:**

I would write a short notice on the card, in the country's local language plus English, something like:

> *Hello, my name is Matthew and I'm lost. Please contact my parents Eric and Melissa on their cell phones +1-123-555-1234 or notify the police or security staff.*

I would not add too many details, but provide enough to make it quick to get in touch with the parents or other guardians. You could also make special-purpose cards if you're often going to a particular mall or playground, or to mention other guardians than the parents (e.g. when on a trip with grandma).

**Layout:**

I would not do much in terms of pretty layout (as in a business card). Just make the text as large as possible, to be easy to read even for youngsters and people who use reading glasses.

**Photo:**

I don't see a reason to add a photo of the child, but you could do that if you want. It might be a good idea to put a photo of the parents on the reverse side, so that the finder knows who to look for.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply. Should I add photo of the child? Can I use contact details of parent as in business card format?

Comment: @AbdulAziz I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

While Torben's ideas are all pretty sound, clear and complete, it is actually **not** a good idea to make such cards too visible.  Slapping something on his back with his name on it actually makes it easier for someone who would take advantage of children to do just that.  Still, put the cards in his backpack, shoe etc. but avoid making it really easy to find his name just walking by even when he is right with you.

You might also put any allergies and medical alerts on such a card - just in case - it doesn't hurt to have that kind of information available too.

I suggest "Free Range Kids" by Leonore Skenazy for more information about how to keep your kids safe and teach them about what they can do for themselves to avoid getting separated and what to do if they do get separated.

Answer (score 2):

Is he in school? You might talk to the school about it. I know my school has a standard form or the like that can be printed with all the appropriate contact info... I mean my school does it all the time, so you might chk if they'll make a copy for you.